# How does my php function for converting a date to facebook timestamp look? New to PHP

Tags: php, facebook, timestamp

any suggestions to make it better?

```
function convertToFBTimestamp($date){
$this_date = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s', strtotime($date));
$cur_date = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s');

list ($this_year, $this_month, $this_day, $this_hour, $this_min, $this_sec) = explode('-',$this_date);
list ($cur_year, $cur_month, $cur_day, $cur_hour, $cur_min, $cur_sec) = explode('-',$cur_date);

$this_unix_time = mktime($this_hour, $this_min, $this_sec, $this_month, $this_day, $this_year);
$cur_unix_time = mktime($cur_hour, $cur_min, $cur_sec, $cur_month, $cur_day, $cur_year);
$cur_unix_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $cur_month, $cur_day, $cur_year);

$dif_in_sec = $cur_unix_time - $this_unix_time;
$dif_in_min = (int)($dif_in_sec / 60);
$dif_in_hours = (int)($dif_in_min / 60);

if(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date))== date('Y-m-d'))
{
    if($dif_in_sec < 60)
    {
        return $dif_in_sec." seconds ago";
    }
    elseif($dif_in_sec < 120)
    {
        return "about a minute ago";
    }
    elseif($dif_in_min < 60)
    {
        return $dif_in_min." minutes ago";
    }
    else
    {
        if($dif_in_hours == 1)
        {
            return $dif_in_hours." hour ago";
        }
        else
        {   
            return $dif_in_hours." hours ago";
        }
    }
}
elseif($cur_unix_date - $this_unix_time < 86400 )
{
    return strftime("Yesterday at %l:%M%P",$this_unix_time);
}
elseif($cur_unix_date - $this_unix_time < 259200)
{
    return strftime("%A at %l:%M%P",$this_unix_time);
}
else 
{
    if($this_year == $cur_year)
    {
        return strftime("%B, %e at %l:%M%P",$this_unix_time);
    }
    else
    {
        return strftime("%B, %e %Y at %l:%M%P",$this_unix_time);
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: Did my answer, or any other answer, solve this problem for you? If so, please mark the most correct one as such, so this Question can be labelled as Answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks pretty good, but, if you are looking for ideas to be able to improve/rewrite it, I have taken your work and slightly adapted it as below:

```
function convertToFBTimestamp( $d ) {
  $d = ( is_string( $d ) ? strtotime( $d ) : $d ); // Date in Unix Time

  if( ( time() - $d ) < 60 )
    return ( time() - $d ).' seconds ago';
  if( ( time() - $d ) < 120 )
    return 'about a minute ago';
  if( ( time() - $d ) < 3600 )
    return (int) ( ( time() - $d ) / 60 ).' minutes ago';
  if( ( time() - $d ) == 3600 )
    return '1 hour ago';
  if( date( 'Ymd' ) == date( 'Ymd' , $d ) )
    return (int) ( ( time() - $d ) / 3600 ).' hours ago';
  if( ( time() - $d ) < 86400 )
    return 'Yesterday at '.date( 'g:ia' , $d );
  if( ( time() - $d ) < 259200 )
    return date( 'l \a\t g:ia' , $d );
  if( date( 'Y' ) == date( 'Y' , $d ) )
    return date( 'F, jS \a\t g:ia' , $d );
  return date( 'j F Y \a\t g:ia' , $d );
}
```

Up to you whether you want to build off this, or keep your existing code, or what-not.

Comment: Oh, and the line `if( ( time() - $d_u ) == 3600 )` might be worth changing to `if( ( time() - $d_u ) < 3900 )` or similar, to allow for a bit of tolerance in what you consider "1 hour ago". 3900, for instance, allows anything up to 1:05 to be considered as 1hr.